# Iptables: rule to accept traffic with local-ip but from remote interface

Tags: iptables, nat

Consider we have a public website `example.com` resolving to `1.1.1.1`. The actual web-server is behind a router/firewall and is listening on port `8080`.

[image: Nat reflection]

Simple setup is OK for internet users, but not for other clients in `192.168.1.0` range. A client in `192.168.1.3` cannot connect to `1.1.1.1:80`. We have  [hairpinning NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) problem, (described also in [mikrotik wiki](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT)).

Suppose, we solve issue not by configuring router, but with `iptables` in web-server itself. This commands instruct all outgoing packets on port 8080 to be sent via router:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -j MARK --set-xmark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table natreflect
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table natreflect
```

The above config solves all clients in `192.168` range, but not clients in `192.168.1.2` itself.

When a client `192.168.1.2`  wants to connect to `1.1.1.1:80`, it sends a packet like `192.168.1.2:34567->1.1.1.1:80` to router. Router does NAT and sends a packet `192.168.1.2:34567->192.168.1.2:8080` to web server (e.g. on its `eth0` interface). Web servers receives this packet. The packet traverses chains `mangle.PREROUTING` and `nat.PREROUTING`, but it doesn't reach to `mangle.INPUT` (and connection does not establish).

What's the problem? (`rp_filter` is set to 0 on all interfaces)

Comment: +1 for this clever trick with mark/table/rule avoiding to do a SNAT for the LAN case, thus not losing or altering informations. Just to be sure, are 192.168.1.1 *and* 1.1.1.1 belonging to the same router? Because the link from mikrotik seems to tell so, but your question isn't that clear on it. If so I think I got all 3 cases (from outside, from LAN, and from router) working without trouble. Why did you write "client `192.168.1.1` ... it sends ... to router" when "client `192.168.1.1` ... sends to itself" seems better? And why NAT from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.1` again, not `192.168.1.2` ?

Comment: Ok got it: the troublesome case is from `192.168.1.2` and I have it too. I think you made a typo when asking the question

Comment: @A.B Thanks, yes there was a typo in using `192.168.1.1` instead of `192.168.1.2`, question edited.  `192.168.1.1` and `1.1.1.1` belongs to same router.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be difficult for the server `192.168.1.2` to accept an incoming packet coming *from* its own IP `192.168.1.2` but from scope *link*, not scope *host*, so from its own IP but which it not itself. That seems a routing problem for which there might or might not be a solution. One can still just work around this situation so it never happens.

To avoid this situation, before even having the initial packet leave the web server `192.168.1.2` and go on the wire, just add an iptables rule on it  redirecting a connection from itself to `1.1.1.1:80` directly to the right place: itself.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

An alternate and equivalent rule (at least on recent kernels, perhaps not on old kernels) would be:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:8080
```

By just adding this rule in addition to the other settings, connections coming from outside, from LAN and from the web server all behave the same: they work, they keep the source IP, and for all cases the destination IP is `192.168.1.2`. The only drawback is to have to know there is `1.1.1.1` .